# Run html2text on all files in a directory that do not have an extention

Tags: bash, conversion, html

I have a directory filled with many files with no extensions that were put there by a call to wget.

I want to use html2text to convert all these files to plain text files.

In other words, how to run this command

```
html2text listbaba=A > listbaba=A.txt
```

but not just on `listbaba=A` but all files in the current directory with *no* extensions. On the internet, one finds this example:

```
 for file in *.html; do html2text "$file" > "$file.txt"; done
```

but the question is by what must I replace `"*.html"` to do it for all files with *no* extentions~

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a `not` flag in a `find` command and iterate over that output.

Find files that do not have an extension, or more specific, files that do not have a dot in their name:

```
find . -type f -not -name "*.*"
```

Iterate over these files and call `html2text`:

```
for file in `find . -type f -not -name "*.*"`; do html2text "$file" > "$file.txt"; done
```

Comment: @kos: I do not really understand your comment. Could you provide it as a solution instead?

Comment: Done, you might want to check the answer

Answer (score 5):

You can negate the globbing pattern:

```
for f in !(*.*); do html2text "$f" > "$f.txt"; done
```

This, differently from using `find` in `for f in "$(find [...])"; do [...]; done` (or by running `find` in a subshell using backticks), won't break on filenames containing newlines (and, FWIW, avoids forking a subshell and running another process).

For this to work you'll need the `extglob` option of `bash` to be turned on in your current `bash` instance; however `extglob` should be on by default:

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ shopt extglob
extglob         on
```

If `extglob` is off, you can turn it on by running:

```
shopt -s extglob
```

and turn it off again by running:

```
shopt -u extglob
```

An example using `echo`:

```
user@debian:~/tmp$ tree
.
├── file1
├── file1.html
├── file2
├── file2.html
├── file3
└── file3.html

0 directories, 6 files
user@debian:~/tmp$ for f in !(*.*); do echo "$f"; done
file1
file2
file3
```